# expire session and redirect in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, codeigniter-3

in my config.php

for session:

```
    $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
    $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
    $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

and for cookie:

```
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
    $config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
    $config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
    $config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
    $config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
    $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

I did this configuration for my default session whatever, I'm gonna use for entire application.

Now I need to set some cookie and session for explicit timeout after 2 hours and redirect user to end that quiz competition session.

```
$data = array(
    'quiz_id' => 2,
    'is_quiz_active' => true
);

$this->session->sess_expiration = '3600';// expires in 1 hours
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
if($this->session->userdata('is_quiz_active')) {
    echo $this->session->userdata('is_quiz_active');
} else {
    redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: You need to set `$config['sess_save_path'] = /some/absolute/path/directory/;` . Read it more in [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver).

Comment: if i set path what will happen? automatically everything will work :) what's this brother i told you to give me some sort of solution on my problem for this i have given my code too.

Comment: need cookie or session to be automatically destroy after giving some time. how to do that i need code syntactically. read my question clearly already stack overflow edited it :(

Comment: You have wrong settings there at first. Read again the link I provided and set everything for basic use. Than you can continue with making code more complex. Pay attention on files and directories permission.